# How to implement jQuery scannerDetection

Tags: jquery, asp.net, barcode, detection, barcode-scanner

I am writing an ASP.Net app that requires barcode scanner detection (my first attempt at ASP.Net so please forgive my lack of knowledge). I don't want the user to have to place the cursor in a specific control before scanning, but rather allow him to scan no matter where the cursor is and have the app detect that a scan was done. I found the jQuery plug in called `scannerDetection` but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work. I put the `jquery.scannerDetection.js` file in my `Scripts` folder (using `VS 2013`) and I added the following to my `SiteMobile.Master` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/scannerDetection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scannerDetection();
    $(window).bind('scannerDetectionComplete', function (e, data) {
      alert('complete ' + data.string);
    })
    .bind('scannerDetectionError', function (e, data) {
      console.log('detection error ' + data.string);
    })
    .bind('scannerDetectionReceive', function (e, data) {
      console.log(data);
    })      
    $(window).scannerDetection('success');      
  });
</script>
```

When I do a test barcode scan, I don't get the `complete` alert. I did try adding a `test` alert at the top of the function and also added an `onChange` reference to a `textbox` for this function and I did get the `test` alert, but not the `complete` alert. Also, the `test` alert fired on both the `.ready` event and the `onChange` event (for my test) and I know that's not what I want. Is there any sample project out there that uses this jQuery plugin that I can look at to figure out what I'm doing wrong? I need very specific instructions since I'm new to both ASP.Net and jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, apparently the solution is this, in the document.ready function, pass the jQuery `$` in the function parameter. 
Example
    `$`(document).ready(function(`$`){ //Do stuff}) this will stop the error in an ASP.NET MVC app